# In std::vector, is vector a class or object?

Tags: c++, class

With std::vector std is a class, and vector is a class or object? If a class then can you nest classes.

Comment: `std` is a namespace not a class.

Comment: `std::vector` is a class. An object of type `std::vector` is an object.

Comment: `std::vector` is a class template. `std::vector<T>` (where T is a type), is a class.

Answer (score 2):

The `std` prefix is a namespace, and it is the canonical namespace for the standard library. The `std::vector` is a generic template type (class) in the standard library namespace, and is documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: So im guessing a namespace is a structure that has a bunch of classes in it, is there any other reason to have them other then keeping two classes named the same separate?

Comment: @Jcodin Namespaces are used for visibility and versioning, and the concept isn't limited to C++. Start by reading http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/